# Set Title from backend data For SEO with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

version : Angular & Universal 7.x.x

If I just call 'titleService.setTitle' during ngOnInit() without backend data,
it works for SEO.

However when I try setting the title after getting the data from backend,
it can not get it.

Here is a example :

```
constructor(private titleService: Title, 
            private backendService: BackendService) {}


ngOnInit() {
   this.backendService.getDetail()
        .subscribe((r: any) => {
            const tt = r.title;
            this.titleService.setTitle(tt);
}
```

It looks like `AngularUniversal` have send a very basic HTML file first that means finishing rendering once
and get more data from javascript job, so the `searchEngine` a Bot did not wait after rendering the result.

I guess a solution is

- if it is  the bot, did not send first HTML rendering
  instead finishing rendering after all javascript job is finish.

or

- `AngularUniversal` works all API communication and render.

I don't know how to make this work.

I am checking results of the bot with this service : https://technicalseo.com/tools/pre-rendering

Comment: Make sure you have no errors server side in the terminal where you started the nodejs process from. This is usually the cause

Comment: There is no errors. What's your point @David ?

Comment: If there was an error during the rendering that could explain why there is no title

Comment: It was my misstakes. I guess I set angualrUniversal with old guide. after add some more codes, It works. I think AngularUniveral works for all renders.